# ajax control toolkit could not find resource

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've just started using ajax control toolkit...I've installed `AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET35` 
and have created a tab named ajax control toolkit in visual studio 2008. My problem is I have just placed the `tabcontainer` in my form. When I run the program, I get the following error:

> "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed."

I've downloaded the `ajaxcontrol` toolkit in my drive & not in c: is that a problem?
is there idea for this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ToolkitScriptManager before your AjaxToolkit controls

Comment: Can you explain more in your answer please ?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I had to use a few Ajax Toolkit controls for an assignment

Just put a ToolkitScriptManager control, which is found in the same tools tab as the other Ajax Toolkit controls, at the top of your form. All following Ajax Toolkit controls should work.